# Insert Read-Only Document in Couchbase

Tags: go, couchbase

Is there any way to Insert Read-Only document or Key-Value pair in Couchbase using couchbase Go SDK?

Comment: It doesn't appear there's a way to do this at all in Couchbase, in any SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this at the document level (yet), but one possible workaround with Couchbase Server *Enterprise* is bucket level permission. You could create a bucket (e.g. "myreadonly") and create a user (e.g "myreadonlyuser") that only has data reader permission. Of course, someone will need write access to put the document in there in the first place, but anyone using the "myreadonlyuser" credentials can only read.

[image: screenshot of Couchbase adding a new user]

There might be a way to do it in the upcoming "scope" and "collection" levels too, but it would likely be a variation of the above approach. Document-level authentication may be on the roadmap for the future.